# How to setup IMAP backend in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-5, imap, email-client

I have a rails 5 application and I have stored emails in mysql database.

**What I want to do:**

- I want to setup an `IMAP backend` in my Rails 5 application
- So that, users can use android and desktop `email client` to connect to my `rails app`
- And sync emails from my database to their email app (`like gmail app`)

---

- I want a very lightweight solution
- If no solution is available, may be, I will build it myself.

So, any `suggestion` / `tips` / `documentation` / `tutorial` is highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be a good place to start - `https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/ruby/imap/a-comprehensive-guide-to-interacting-with-imap-using-ruby.html`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna thanks for your suggestion. But I am not trying to fetch email from other IMAP server. I want to run my own IMAP server. So, other IMAP client can connect to my IMAP service.

Comment: What you need is an imap server written in ruby. That's easy to find, but asking for recommentations for such things is off-topic for stack overflow, so I'll vote to close.